# What tools allows me to keep track of html tags when doing web development?

Tags: html, tags, tracking

What tools allows me keep track of tags when doing web development? For example, I would like to be able to quickly find whether I missed closing a div tag.

At the moment I am using notepad++ to write html. It highlights starting and ending tags, but it can take me time to review almost all tags to find where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is pretty much the de-facto standard for this kind of thing nowadays

[Tidy Windows Installer](http://dev.int64.org/tidy.html)

[Tidy FAQ](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/faq.html)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I'm writing a page from scratch I indent the tags so the inner ones are nested within the outer tags.

Ex:

```
<body>
    <div>
       Content here...
    </div>
</body>
```

I also write out the opening and closing tags at the same time, plan out the page layout, and then go back and fill in the content later.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the opening and closing tags at the same time. You could indent. Choosing an IDE or tool specifically for that seems a little bit overkill in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go past proper indentation, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Developer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for Firefox is very handy. It gives you a good way to highlight different tags on the page and makes it easy to visualize them.  Also has too many tools to list here, including HTML and CSS validators.

Answer (score -1):

Indenting is helpful. I also find the [Html Validator](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/) extension for Firefox to be handy for checking for HTML issues once you're viewing the page in the browser (which is especially handy for checking server-generated HTML).

Comment: Unfortunately, this extension does not catch missing ending tags. The reason for this is that it only looks at the parsed DOM, and the browser will handle missing ending tags while parsing the DOM.

Comment: I imagine that changed since 2008. It's helpful to know that's an issue now.